# Variables dentro de un modelo Laravel

Tags: laravel, sql-server, eloquent

No se si mi pregunta tenga sentido. 
Estoy trabajando en sql server.
Y lo que quiero hacer es tener en mis modelos los esquemas dinamicos.

Ejemplo:

Tengo este modelo.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CatalogoUno extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Constructor.Tiendas_Ropa.CatalogoUno';
    protected $primaryKey = 'TiendaID';
}
```

Pero también tengo este otro modelo.

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CatalogoUno extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Constructor.Tiendas_Zapatos.CatalogoUno';
    protected $primaryKey = 'TiendaID';
}
```

Como yo lo pienso es algo asi.

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CatalogoUno extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'Constructor.'.$schema.'.CatalogoUno';
    protected $primaryKey = 'TiendaID';
}
```

Pero no se como le puedo pasar la variable cuando llamo el modelo, que es cuando sabría que esquema voy a utilizar.

El fin de hacer esto es no hacer demasiados modelos. Dato que los esquemas tienen la misma estructura en cuanto tablas.

Solo que en la empresa en la que trabajo me piden tener esquemas por organización.

Se que esto también lo puedo hacer con QueryBuilder pero en verdad prefiero utilizar eloquent y olvidarme de algunos temas.

Si tienen alguna idea de como hacer esto o tienen alguna sugerencia no duden en decirme. Igual si tienen alguna respuesta en algún otro idioma hagan mela saber de antemano muchas gracias.

Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

No lo he probado y ahora mismo no puedo pero en teoría algo así debería de funcionar.

```
    namespace App\Models;

    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class CatalogoUno extends Model
    {
        protected $table;
        protected $primaryKey = 'TiendaID';

        public function __construct($schema , array $attributes = []) {
           parent::__construct($attributes);
           $this->table = 'Constructor.'.$schema.'.CatalogoUno';
        }
    }


//Como mandar la varible
$cat = new CatalogoUno('Tiendas_Ropa');
```

Comment: Ojo porque al definir un `__construct()` en `CatalogoUno` estás pisando el de `Model`. Tendrías que llamar a `parent::__construct($attributes)` y modificarlo a `__construct($schema, array $attributes = [])`. De esa forma se puede seguir usando el `__construct()` de Eloquent.

Comment: gracias @azeós toda la razón!

Comment: Excelente pensé que en los modelos no podía cargar un constructor.

Comment: Aplique su sugerencia, el modelo instanciado si construye bien el nombre de la tabla pero cuando intento hacer un consulta tipo $cat->all();  Me da un error y es porque la tabla no esta bien instanciada.

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega podrías editar la pregunta y poner exactamente que error te está generando?

Comment: @AlbertoOrtega has probado con App\CatalagoUno::all(); ??

Comment: Al parecer la instancia no guardaba la variable con el $schema y el constructor dejaba vacía la variable. Lo solucione con variables de sesión ahora lo unico que tengo que hacer es instanciar el modelo con la variable que ocupe y ya me deja hacer cualquier tipo de consultas en el esquema deseado.